# PyCharm Selenium not openening Chrome, "Process finished with exit code 0"

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, pycharm

I am trying to run this simple code, but when I run it, it simply says "Process finished with exit code 0". I am new to Selenium, and have no idea why it wont open.

Selenium seems to be correctly installed, and the chromedriver is in the path described - anyone who knows what to do about this?

Code entered

[image: 1]

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

PATH = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.google.dk/")